# Is there a way to inspect or change the resolution negotiated between MacOS and a USB webcam?

Tags: resolution, monterey, webcam

I use a Dell Ultrasharp webcam, which supports up to 4k resolution. On a Windows device, I am getting that full resolution and a pretty good overall image, provided my lightning is good.

Connecting this webcam to my 2019 MBP running Monterey 12.1, it does work, it does give me a video, and can be used in applications like Photo Booth or MS Teams. Since Dell provides no application for the webcam for MacOS, I use the Webcam Settings app to optimize some aspects like Zoom level, Focus and so on.

My problem is that the video stream obviously does not make use of the full capability of the webcam. I can't say for certain what resolution it emits, but when checking the video in Photo Booth as a no-frills least common denominator, it looks more like 720p. The video metrics in MS Teams show a relatively small resolution as well (though I do not know if that is because of the webcam or server-side settings restricting the resolution or bandwidth). The issue is clearly pixelation, not just a blurred image which could stem from wrong focus or a dirty lens.

So far, I found no way to get *any* insight into the internal processing between the webcam and MacOS (while the 3rd party Webcam Settings app does give me pretty sufficient control over all the features, it does not seem to show any debug info of any kind). Is there a way to find out, for example, whether the Mac "thinks" that the webcam only supports 720p? Or an option telling the Mac to go to the full resolution?

If it matters, I made sure to connect it with a direct and original Apple USB-C <-> USB-C cable (normally I'm going through a USB hub), but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution between the camera and macOS is not as such negotiated and fixed at the time the camera is connected to the computer. Instead, every time a program requests access to a camera, they can also request for a specific resolution or various other features that cameras provide.

Unfortunately that level of functionality is only for supported cameras. For non-supported cameras you get the default settings that is baked into the camera - it is thus not really changeable by the operating system, as there's no set standard for communicating settings to the cameras (such as changing field of view, applying HDR, AI autoframing, etc).

Some programs have an "info" button or menu item that gives you information on the camera resolution in use - but not all of them. Some times you can save the camera image, and then look at the resulting image file to see the resolution.

In general, support for a specific camera usually comes in the form of a driver and/or a small application that allows you to change settings. For your camera this application is known as the Dell Peripheral Manager - and Dell explicitly writes on their web site and in their data sheet that this is not supported for macOS.

So basically Dell isn't writing software for their camera for macOS, so you're stuck with the default settings within the camera plus whatever third parties can "reverse engineer" and trick the camera into doing without vendor support. It's really too bad as the camera's design is heavily inspired by Apple's iSight camera, so you would think that it was intended for Macs as well.

From my experience this means you're basically stuck with 1080p on that camera. As far as I know, the only program that can enable 4k on this camera is [OBS](https://obsproject.com). You might be able to use OBS to route the camera input into a new virtual camera that can then be used by other programs (such as for video conferencing). It is going to be complicated setup that requires extra CPU power for processing. I would consider returning the camera and buying a different one.

Comment: Very helpful. I installed OBS and it indeed shows 1080p as you say. So insofar you have answered one of the main subquestions of how to get the information about what resolution is delivered. Interestingly, even though OBS shows 1920x1080 here, the image still "looks" like a much lower resolution (i.e., I'm displaying it on an external monitor with native 1920x1080 for testing purposes and it looks nowhere as sharp as it could). I'll strongly think about returning the cam. What a shame!